# Quickly filter video with SurfaceViewGL

Tags: java, android

The video in my application is displayed through SurfaceViewGL. The video comes from MediaPlayer to Surface, then the filter specified in the fragment shader is applied and then everything is displayed on the screen. 
The rendered video with the filter applied is written to the file.

The problem is that MediaPlayer is sending frames too slowly to Surface. And everything overlaps in real time, which is too long.

Is there a way to quickly apply a shader filter to a video?

I thought just to speed up the video, but how will it behave when further slowed down, and can MediaRecorder even capture it?

Comment: Hi' Why do you need to encode and display the video at the same time? The encoding could be done separately without displaying the video. I haven't tried processimg video on android, but FFmpeg is a flexible library for processing video, maybe it can be compiled for android?

Comment: @gregn3 I use FFMPEG to encode video, the problem here is that not all filters can be implemented using it. I do not need to display filters on the video while applying the filter to the whole video!

Comment: Why use MediaPlayer to decode the video then? Just decode the frames with FFmpeg and send them to the Surface from your own code ?

Comment: @gregn3 
I am using [link](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg). I do not know how to directly output to SurfaceViewGL through FFMPEG.

Comment: I don't know how to do that either, so would need to Google it or dig into FFmpeg's code, and the same for SurfaceViewGL. Seems like need to get the frames from FFmpeg and then send them to SurfaceViewGL. That's 2 separate steps. It could be a possible alternative if you get stuck with MediaPlayer.